# Как настроить свайп в плагине Swiper?

Tags: swiper

Есть вертикальный слайдер Swiper. Нужно чтоб он работал от свайпа на телефонах/планшетах. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

На официальном сайте [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/) есть [примеры](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/):

Вертикальный слайдер - https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/090-vertical.html, который работает под ваши требования.

На случай дополнительной настройки, есть прекрасно расписанное [API](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/).